# Edit marshmallow hosts file

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, hosts-file

I'm trying to edit the hosts file on the Marshmallow emulator, but I can't do it. I use ADB tool:

1. I start emulator using emulator.exe
2. `adb mount`
3. `adb pull /system/etc/hosts c:\temp`
4. Then I edit `hosts` file
5. `ADB push c:\temp\hosts /system/etc` (this step doesn't work, because I get error - "read-only file system").

Also, I tried to do `adb shell` and then `SU` commands and then `mount -o rw,remount /system`. But every time when I try to edit hosts file, I get the error that file system is read only.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the remount:

```
    adb shell
    setenforce 0 
    mount -o rw,remount /system 
    setenforce 1
```

Answer (score 0):

These steps work for me (Windows 8.1 and Android Studio emulator (qemu))

1. Open a Command Prompt
2. `cd %localappdata%\Android\sdk\tools`
3. Run the emulator from the command line with -writable-system flag, e.g. 
   `emulator -avd (your AVD name) -writable-system`

While the emulator is booting (wait until the Android splash appears):

4. `cd %localappdata%\Android\sdk\platform-tools`
5. `adb root` (do not proceed until this command has been successful)
6. `adb remount`
7. `adb push c:\temp\hosts /system/etc/hosts`